# how to get the class name through selenium

Tags: selenium

```
 <table >
<tr class="odd First"><td>1one Cell</td><td>2one Cell</td><td>3one Cell</td><td>4one Cell</td> </tr>
<tr class="even Second"><td>Two Cell</td><td>2Two Cell</td><td>3Two Cell</td><td>4Two Cell</td></tr>
<tr class="odd Thrid"><td>1Three Cell</td><td>2Three Cell</td><td>3Three Cell</td><td>4Three Cell</td></tr>
<tr class="even Fourth"><td>1Five Cell</td><td>2Five Cell</td><td>3Five Cell</td><td>4Five Cell</td></tr>       
</table>
```

How can i get the class names of the tr. Please suggest me.

Comment: which language are you using and the driver type?

Comment: not using any driver. Simply using selenium

Answer (score 13):

To get the class names of all the  tags using java.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

for(WebElement ele:list){
   String className = ele.getAttribute("class");
   System.out.println("Class name = "+className);
}
```

This will print all the class names to the console for all the  tags on the web page.

```
String className = selenium.getAttribute("//html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/@class");
```

May be this code might get you the value of the first  tag's class name. Let me know if this works.

Comment: This will work only when you use Selenium Webdriver. For Selenium RC it will not work

Answer (score 0):

```
List0 = []
List1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/table/tr')
for element in List1:
    name = element.get_attribute('class')
    List0.append(name)
print(List0)
```